# PyQt QTreeWidgetItem Individual windows with individual data.

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget that contains rows of data for multiple students. When double clicking on a row, a window opens, with a number of drop down menus and text edits that a user can input into. Currently, the user can open the file menu in the top left corner of that window and save the file manually in a folder from there and also open it, but this is inefficient for my program, and I want to make it so that each individual student in the QTreeWidget will have their own individual window open up, that, when a save button is pressed in the window, the data within the window will save within a database of some sort, and when that student's window is opened again, the information inputted specifically in the window and saved earlier for that student will load up automatically.

The QTreeWidget looks something like this (ignore the issue with the scroll bar in the corner. Names have been censored for data protection):

[QTreeWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwgSj.png)

And the window containing user inputted data looks like so:

[Popup Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFjvj.png)

If there are any documentations or tutorials that could help me with this issue, I'd love to know, because I can't seem to find anything related to this anywhere. Even any basic ideas on how I could go about introducing this function into my program would be of great help. I am using Python 3.4 and MySql.

Comment: Have you read Summerfield's book on pyqt programming? This question is just too general for this site: you are basically asking how to make a fully functional GUI application in PyQt. I recommend you read Summerfield's book on PyQt, and also study how to ask questions here because this is like your seventh in which you have not followed advice on how to ask questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am not asking how to make a fully functional application, I asked for basic ideas or documentations, not full thought out plans or code of how to make it. I gave explicit detail of what I wanted my program to do. Reading the book won't help me because I have severe time constraints. I have asked this question as best I could, and received a solid response from @lps with a link to a tutorial that matches the explanation I have given.

Comment: So in your question you said you couldn't find anything anywhere, but it sounds like you couldn't find anything that would give you an answer very quickly under severe time constraints (because there are actually a few books out there). You can work through Summerfield's book relatively fast to get what you need. Or one of the other PySide books, which is pretty much the same as PyQt. You have to learn to walk before you can run. Good luck trying to run first. :)

Comment: I'm not going to read any of those books since I already have simple documentation and tutorials offered to me by someone who has tried to actually help me out, instead of give me a GENERIC answer. You've been of absolute no help in every question I've posted, and just repeated the same post regarding my questions that they cannot be answered, despite the fact that people have been able to answer and help. I've got an answer, and I said it was what I needed, therefore your input on this question is useless for me.

Comment: The book I recommended was not a generic book. It was a very specific book that would answer your very generic questions. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you start with studying how the standard MVC is implemented in Qt?

The following resources should be a good start for you:

[this intro site](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/introduction-pyqt4/)

[or this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sRoLN337cs&list=PL8B63F2091D787896)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I need.